# ¿Enviar id por url por medio de menú desplegable?

Tags: php

Debo enviar por url el id que obtengo de una base de datos por medio de una consulta al seleccionar el elemento haciendo uso de un elemento , lo que necesito es que al seleccionar me envie a otra pagina para mostrar el resto de datos de este id. Tengo esa función por medio de javascript.

Código

```
    <form name="lista" method="post" action="selection.php">
    <div id="participantes">
        <label><select name="" class="form-control" onchange="javascript:handleSelect(this)">
            
            <?php include 'conexion/conexion.php'; 

                $consulta = "SELECT * FROM jugador";
                $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conect,$consulta) or die(mysql_error($conect));
            ?>
            <?php

                foreach ($ejecutar as $opciones):

            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $opciones["id"] ?>"><?php echo $opciones["id"] ?></option>
            <?php
                endforeach
            ?>

        </select></label>
        
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function handleSelect(id)
                {
                    window.location ="selection.php?id=<?php echo $opciones ?>"
                }

            </script>
    </div>
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: OK, según estoy entendiendo. Estás en una página, donde tienes un <form> el cual viene anidado por un query el cual te carga las <option> dentro de un <select> y al select le agregaste un inline js en el cual detecte cualquier cambio de opcion. Entonces, al detectar el cambio, debería llamar a la función en la cual usas window.location con tu código PHP. ¿Me explicas en que parte está fallando el código? Así puedo ayudarte mejor.

Comment: El problema es que al seleccionar no mes esta generando ninguna acción, no sale ningun error solo no hace nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente tenías que obtener el ID mediante JavaScript y almacenarlo en una variable para así poder usar con el `window.location`, te recomiendo que pongas el código JS antes del body tag. así mismo, te acomodé el `<label>` tag que lo estabas usando de manera incorrecta.

En `window.location` utilizé algo conocido como **template literal** los cuales son literales de texto que habilitan el uso de expresiones incrustadas, en este caso, usamos el ${id} para referirnos al id almacenado arriba.

Como última recomendación, evita utilizar **inline js** ya que se vuelve muy dificil de mantener en aplicaciones grandes, además, su funcionalidad no puede ser testeada en otras páginas.

**HTML/PHP**

```
<form name="lista" method="post" action="selection.php">
    <div id="participantes">
        <label for="opciones">Opciones</label>
        <select name="opciones" class="form-control" id="miSeleccion" onchange="handleSelect()">
        
            <?php include 'conexion/conexion.php'; 
                $consulta = "SELECT * FROM jugador";
                $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conect, $consulta) or die(mysql_error($conect));
            ?>

            <?php foreach ($ejecutar as $opciones): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $opciones["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $opciones["id"]; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach;?>

        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>

    // Funcion para detectar el cambio de opciones.
    function handleSelect(){
    
        // Obtiene el ID de la selección deseada.
        var id = document.getElementById("miSeleccion").value;
    
        // Se cambia a la ventana deseada gracias al id almacenado en la variable.
        window.location = `selection.php?id=${id}`;
    
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado. Mil gracias.

Comment: Si te sirvió, te invito a marcar la respuesta como correcta :D